# c# LPT Control all pins. Not 8

Tags: c#, .net, dll, hardware, lpt

I can control 8 pins in LPT using inpout.dll.
I want to control some LPT device but I need to use more than 8 pins.
How to do it?

[image: example]

It can be COM or NET dll.
I have no idea how to control more than 8 pins.

Comment: I don't think this has much to do with programming as it does with hardware.

Comment: What sort of a LPT port is it... ? Is it a standard LPT that is visibly becoming extinct? Or is it a proprietary board? If its the latter, you'll have to consult with the manufacturer's website....

Comment: You cannot effectively control a stepper motor with a PC.  Your program will lose the CPU occasionally, you'll stop generating pulses.  *Very* bad for the motor.  You need a stepper controller.

Comment: This is board that is connected to pc by LPT. I read about control pinst and strobe pins somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/Inpout32_read.aspx it's in VB.NET but i'm sure you can figure out how to translate it ;)

Answer (score 1):

[MUX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer) maybe?

It can help you manipulate certain amount of bits by using less bits. By using 7 of them you could use the last X to multiplex others:

6 (data) + 1 (selector) => 12 bits
5 + 2 => 20 bits
4 + 3 => 32 bits
3 + 4 => 48 bits
2 + 5 => 64 bits

But this is not a programming question anyway. You will have to attach a multiplexer and a demultiplexer on the other side.

> BTW: What kind of an LPT port is this, since [LPT port has **lots** of pins]. 25 and not just 7 or 8. Your holes for a connector are not really related to LPT port. At least it doesn't really look like they would be. Unless they are serialized. It seems there are 4 LPT ports on your *connector* + enable, ground & power supply (Vcc)

Comment: LPT has 25 pins. 8 data, 8 ground, 4 status, 4 control, 1 unused.
Out pins are: data and control.
I don't know how to control "contreol pins".